# Combine multiple columns containing similar values into one column for use in graph inside Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

I have 3 fields, Action1, Action2 and Action3 contained in one report.  Each Action field is selected from the same list of values.  I would like to graph a count of these values by the value of the field and not field itself.  I need one graph and not one graph per Action field.  I have tried to combine the field values into an array in the details section, but the report shows the concatenated string values "Action1, Action2, Action3', as a single value in the graph.  I tried to graph using "on change of", but it will only allow 2 fields and not 3.  Is there a way to count these values regardless of the Action field where they are found?

I have been working with Crystal for years, but can't figure this out for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to find a solution to this issue inside of Crystal Reports itself.  What I ended up doing was creating a stored procedure in SQL to use as the data source.  In the stored procedure I basically performed a cross join such that there was only 1 Action returned per record.  In CR I then was able to summarize the Action field values.